# How do I calculate conditional probabilities from data

Tags: matlab, dataset, probability, bayesian-networks

I'm doing a naive Bayes in Matlab, and it was all good until they said I needed the conditional probabilities. Now I know the formula for conditional p(A|B) = P(A and B)/p(B), but when I have data to get it from I'm lost. The data is:

```
1,0,3,0,?,0,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,3,2,2,1,2,2,0,2,2,2,2,1,2,2,2,3,2,1,1,1,3,3,2,2,1,2,2,2,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,2,2
1,0,3,3,1,0,3,1,3,1,1,1,1,1,3,3,1,2,2,0,0,2,2,2,1,2,1,3,2,3,1,1,1,3,3,2,2,2,1,2,2,2,1,2,2,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,2,2
1,0,3,3,2,0,3,3,3,1,1,1,0,3,3,3,1,2,1,0,0,2,2,2,1,2,2,3,2,3,1,3,3,3,1,2,2,1,2,2,2,1,2,2,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,2
1,0,2,3,2,1,3,3,3,1,2,1,0,3,3,1,1,2,2,0,0,2,2,2,2,1,3,2,3,3,1,3,3,3,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,1,2,2,2,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2
1,0,3,2,1,1,3,3,3,2,2,2,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,0,0,2,2,2,1,1,2,3,2,2,1,1,1,3,2,1,2,2,1,2,2,2,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,2,2
1,0,3,3,2,0,3,3,3,1,2,2,0,3,3,3,2,2,1,0,0,1,2,2,2,1,3,3,1,2,2,3,3,3,2,1,2,2,1,2,2,2,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,2
1,0,3,2,1,0,3,3,3,1,2,1,2,3,3,3,3,2,2,0,0,2,2,2,2,1,3,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,2,1,1,2,2,1,2,1,2,2,2,2,1,2,2,2,2,1,2,2,2,1,2
1,0,2,2,1,0,3,1,3,3,3,3,2,1,3,3,1,2,2,0,0,1,1,2,1,2,1,3,2,1,1,3,3,3,2,2,1,2,1,2,2,1,2,2,2,1,2,2,2,1,2,2,2,2,1,2,2
1,0,3,1,1,0,3,1,3,1,1,1,3,2,3,3,1,2,2,0,0,2,2,2,1,2,1,2,1,1,1,3,3,3,3,2,2,1,2,2,2,1,2,2,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,2,2
2,0,2,3,2,0,2,2,2,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,3,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,2,1,2,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,3,2,1,1,2,2
2,0,2,2,0,0,3,2,3,1,1,3,1,3,1,1,2,2,2,0,2,1,1,2,1,1,2,2,2,2,1,3,3,3,1,2,2,1,2,2,2,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2
2,0,2,3,2,0,1,2,1,1,2,1,0,1,2,2,1,2,1,0,2,2,2,2,1,2,1,2,2,3,1,3,3,3,1,2,2,1,2,2,2,2,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,2,2,1
2,0,2,1,1,0,1,2,2,1,2,1,1,2,2,2,1,2,2,0,2,2,2,2,1,2,1,3,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,1,2,2,2,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,2,2
2,0,2,2,1,1,2,3,3,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,1,2,2,0,1,2,2,2,1,2,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,3,2,1,1,2,1,2,2,2,1,2,2,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,2,2
2,1,3,0,?,1,1,2,2,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,2,2,0,2,2,2,2,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,1,1,2,1,2,2,2,2,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,2,1
2,0,3,2,2,1,2,2,2,1,1,2,1,2,3,3,2,2,2,0,1,2,2,2,1,2,3,2,2,1,2,2,2,3,1,3,2,1,2,2,2,1,2,2,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2
2,0,3,2,2,0,1,1,3,1,1,1,0,1,3,3,1,2,2,0,2,2,2,2,1,1,2,2,2,2,1,3,3,3,3,3,1,2,2,1,2,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,2,2
2,0,2,1,1,0,2,1,3,1,1,1,0,3,1,3,1,2,2,0,0,1,2,2,3,3,3,2,2,2,1,3,3,3,1,1,1,2,1,2,2,2,1,2,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,2,2
2,0,2,0,?,0,2,3,3,3,2,1,0,2,2,1,1,1,2,0,0,2,1,2,1,2,3,2,2,3,1,3,3,3,2,1,1,2,1,2,2,2,3,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,2
2,0,1,2,1,0,3,3,3,1,2,2,1,1,3,3,1,2,2,0,0,2,2,2,1,2,1,3,2,3,1,1,1,3,1,1,2,2,1,2,2,2,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,2,2,1
2,0,2,0,?,1,3,3,3,1,2,1,1,3,3,3,1,2,2,0,0,2,2,2,2,1,1,2,3,2,1,1,1,3,1,3,1,1,2,2,2,1,2,2,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,2,2,1,2,2
2,0,3,3,2,0,2,1,3,1,1,3,3,3,3,3,1,2,2,0,0,2,2,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,2,2,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,2,2,2,2,2,1,2
3,0,2,3,1,1,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,1,2,2,2,2,1,2,1,1,1,1,2,2,3,1,3,3,3,1,1,1,3,1,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,1,3,3,2,2,1
3,0,2,3,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,2,2,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,1,3,3,3,2,2,2,3,3,1,1,2,2,3,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1
3,0,3,3,1,0,3,3,1,1,1,2,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,2,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,2,2,2,2,1
3,0,2,3,2,0,1,2,2,1,2,1,2,1,1,1,2,1,2,2,1,2,1,2,2,1,3,2,1,1,2,2,2,2,1,1,2,2,?,2,1,1,1,2,2,2,1,2,2,2,1,3,1,2,2,1,2
3,0,2,2,2,0,2,1,2,1,1,1,0,2,2,3,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,2,2,1,2,2,2,2,3,1,2,2,2,2,1,2,1,1,2,2,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,2,1
3,0,2,2,1,0,2,2,2,1,1,2,0,2,2,2,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,2,1,3,3,3,1,3,3,2,2,3,1,2,1,3,2,2,3,2,2,2,3,3,3,2,2,3,2,2,2,2,1
3,0,3,2,2,0,2,2,2,1,1,2,0,2,2,2,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,2,1,1,3,1,3,3,3,2,3,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,1,2,2,2,2,2
3,0,2,1,1,0,2,2,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,2,1,2,0,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,1,2,1,3,3,3,1,1,3,3,3,2,3,1,2,2,3,3,2,2,2,3,2,2,2,2,2,2,1
3,0,2,3,2,1,2,2,3,1,1,2,1,2,2,2,1,2,2,0,2,2,2,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,1,2,2,3,2,2,2,1,2,2,2,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,2,2
3,0,2,3,1,0,2,3,3,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,1,2,2,0,2,2,2,2,1,2,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,1,2,2,2,1,2,2,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2
```

Where the classes are in the first column from 1 to 3 the ? I will change them as the mean of the column, the prior of the class well that can be done by counting as class #/total of first column. That is simple, but the conditionals?

```
       ---class---
      /   /   \    \
     x1  x2...x_i  xn
```

Bayes p(c|x) = p(x|c)p(c)/p(x). Thanks.

EDIT: What I think I need is, someone who can explain the process of getting the conditionals from data, with apples if possible if I need to do a CPT and give me pointers on how to do it, I'm a programmer mostly.

Comment: Can you clarify: the data is a 32-by-57 matrix? The first column contains the classes from 1 to 3 (c?). What's in the other columns (x?)?

Comment: Yes, The data described 3 types of pathological lung cancers. The Authors give no information on the individual variables nor on where the data was originally used. 
Exactly like you said a 32x57, first column classes, others it doesn't say, thanks.

Comment: I think we should try to re-write your data in a suitable way. You have: 9*56 = 504 observations where class 1 is associated with events from 0 to 3; then 13*56 = 728 observations where class2 is associated with other events; and 10*56 = 560 observations where class 3 is associated with other events, always between 0 and 3. Is this correct?

Comment: I think so, each row is one observation, where the variables from x1 to x56 are, from class of the first column, like the last row is from class 3 and x1=0, etc.

Comment: I don't understand: how many variables do you have? I think you only have two variables: 3 classes and 4 outcomes. Isn't it so?

Comment: Nope, the data has 56 variables x1, ..., x56 and the classes in this data falls into are 1, 2 , 3, the first column the rest are the variables, I could do it with naivebayes.fit in Matlab but I'm trying to understand how is it done. Cheers.

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't understand the problem: you need a conditional probability for *each* of your 56 variables? In other words you want a matrix 3-by-4-by-56 of conditional probabilities?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40538/discussion-between-pedro-alonso-and-francesco)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a brute-force code. Just to be exactly sure we are talking about the same problem.

```
% 1º step: Write the 32-by-56 matrix (excluding column of classes),
% replacing "?" with nans. Name it "data".

% Check the values in data:
unique(data(~isnan(data)))
% These are 0, 1, 2 and 3

% 2º step: Find mean of each variable without considering the NaN values
data_mean = nanmean(data);

% 3º step: replace missing values with class sample mean
data_new = data;
for hh = 1:56
  inds = isnan(data(:, hh));
  data_new(inds, hh) = data_mean(hh);
end
% Only NaN values have been replaced:
find(isnan(data(:)))    % indices of NaN values in data
find(data_new(:) ~= data(:))    % indices of data_new different from data

% 4º step: compute probabilities of outcome conditional to each class
n = [0, 9, 22, 32]; % indices for classes
probs = zeros(56, 3, 4);
for hh = 1:56 % for each variable
  for ii = 1:3 % for each class
    inds = (n(ii)+1):n(ii+1);
    for jj = 1:4 % for each outcome
      probs(hh, ii, jj) = sum(data(inds, hh) == jj-1);
    end
  end
end

% The conditional probability of the outcome conditional to the class, for
% the first variable is
squeeze(probs(1, :, :))
```